# Sending emails from a web site, when the users also use Google Apps

Tags: php, email, dns, google-apps, spf

We are developing a custom web app for a client.
This app is on a separate server, server.com, than the client's web site, www.client.com.
Each user of our app has an email address like user1@client.com, user2@client.com, etc.
The client is using Google Apps for business for their user emails (like user1@client.com).

Now here's what we need: 
Each user needs to be able to send certain emails to people on his contact list. Those emails are from our box, server.com. But we want the From and Reply-To address to be the user who sent it, e.g., user2@client.com.

How can we set up our box, server.com, to be an authorized sender of emails from "client.com"? I looked up the SPF record for Google apps, and it is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

(1) How do we add "server.com" to this SPF record?
(2) From PHP (this is why it's a programming question), how can we ensure that the email, while sent from our server.com, still says "From: user2@client.com" ?

Thanks!

Comment: serverfault will probably be more helpful with your SPF question.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about that but because the question stems from a programming need, I asked it here. I'll ask there also.

Comment: This kinda cross the chasm.  What you need is a mail client in whatever language you are coding the project in.  You can authenticate against www.client.com and should be able to send email via Google's smtp relay.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1. just do `v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all` This assumes that client.com has the A record set to server.com